# Unable to create a share on my Proliant micro server OS Name Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: networking, file-sharing

I recently installed an update on my device and now I am unable to create a share with the drives i was sharing prior to the update.
Every time i do an update of software i have to un-share these drives and then re-share and at times having to turn off all sharing and turn back on again after a restart, but his time i was unable to re-share from properties on the drives.
I get this error please advise

```
net usershare' returned error 255: [2023/05/08 07:58:12,  0] ../../lib/util/debug.c:1100(reopen_one_log)
  reopen_one_log: Unable to open new log file 'Movies/log.net': No such file or directory
net usershare add: share name /media/janice/movies contains invalid characters (any of %<>*?|/\+=;:",)
```

Comment: I have not tried any commands or installs at this stage